# Find a non-abelian group such that $(ab)^{12} = a^{12} b^{12}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism

The question is:

Knowing that $\displaystyle f_{12}( g) \ =\ g^{12}$,

1. Find a group $\displaystyle G$ non-abelian so that $\displaystyle
       f_{12}$ is a homomorphism and prove.
2. Find $\displaystyle |ker\ f_{12} |$ and $\displaystyle |img\ f_{12}
       |$.

Tip: Langrange can help.

My intution:

I feel like the permutation group $\displaystyle S_{3}$ could help. I know $\displaystyle S_{3}$ is non-abelian and I can easily prove it.

To prove that $\displaystyle f_{12}$ is a homomorphism I would have to prove that for all $\displaystyle \sigma ,\ \tau \in S_{3}$:

$\displaystyle ( \sigma \tau )^{12} \ =\ \sigma ^{12} \tau ^{12}$.

I know lagrage stastes that for all $\displaystyle g\in G\ :\ o( g) \ |\ \ |G|$.

And since I know that $\displaystyle |G|\ =\ 3!\ =\ 6$. I can conlcude that the order of each $\displaystyle \sigma \in S_{3}$ is either $\displaystyle 1,2,3,6$. Since $\displaystyle 12$ is a multiple of each, by taking the power of $\displaystyle 12$, no matter which element, I will always get $\displaystyle e$. From here that:

$\displaystyle ( \sigma \tau )^{12} \ =e\ =\ ee\ =\ \sigma ^{12} \tau ^{12} \ $

And I prove homomorphism.

From the same logic, I would get $\displaystyle |ker\ f_{12} |\ =\ 6$. Since it's the whole group. Since, as I said, each element to the power of $\displaystyle 12\ $should be $\displaystyle e$.

From here also that $\displaystyle img\ f_{12} \ =\ e$ and $\displaystyle |img\ f_{12} |\ =\ 1$ . Since the only element you get by multipying to the power of $\displaystyle 12$, as I said, it's $\displaystyle e$.

Is my answer correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. You can do the same for $A_3$, or find an example where $f_{12}$ is more interesting.

Comment: @Berci $A_3$ is Abelian, though.

Comment: Sure, I thought about $A_4$, sorry..